# Using Open Graph meta tags

Tags: html

I am using Open Graph meta tags in my HTML code but I am not sure about its(og:image) property with following content:
This are my codes:

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="Donya Internatioanl group"//>
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://dig.af/" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="~/Images/myImage.jpg" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Some description about this image" />
        <meta property="og:locale" content="fa_GB" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="DIG" />
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
```

Please help me whether this link to image is correct or no:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="~/Images/myImage.jpg" />
```

specially its content, or I have to write it like This:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://mywebsite.net/assets/opengraph/theogimage.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the full path, so:

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://mywebsite.net/blah/image.jpg/>`

would be the correct way. The content has to refer to an URL that Facebook can access and download your image from.